# Bringing up the iPhone keyboard by clicking a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

How can I bring up the iphone keyboard by clicking a button - I haven't created any text fields. My intention is to have labels that hold a single character.

Other people have asked this and it has been answered but it was from years ago and I didn't understand what people meant in there responses.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you explain, what are you going to do after showing keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way you could do this is via hidden `UITextField`, and set that textField to `becomeFirstResponder`

you could hide the text field  in your code liket his `textfield.hidden=YES;` 
or you could hide the textfield from nib file also by going into the attribute inspector and tick the `Hidden` property

You could have a look at this [UIKeyInput- Displaying keyboard in iPhone without UITextField or UITextView](http://www.ioslearner.com/uikeyinput-displaying-keyboard-iphone-uitextfield-uitextview/), I have not tried myself this

Comment: how could I hide a UITextField?

Comment: `textfield.hidden = YES;`  or you could hide the textfield from nib file also by going into the attribute inspector and tick the Hidden property

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden `UITextFeild` as `tempTF` and when the button clicked. call `becomeFirstResponder` of this `textFeild`:

```
[self.tempTF becomeFirstResponder];
```

To Hide textField:

```
UITextField *tempTF = [[UITextField alloc] init]; 
tempTF.hidden = YES
```

or mark Hidden ir your Interface Builder

Comment: How could I add a hidden text field as tempTF?

Comment: UITextField *tempTF = [UITextField alloc] init]; tempTF.hidden = YES;

Comment: you are welcome, if this works for you , please mark my answer as correct answer to help others who ask same question

Answer (score 0):

Attach the button to a touchUpInside event and call **becomeFirstResponder** on the `textView` or `textfield`:

**Here is an example (to bring it up when a text view is clicked):**

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
   [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: How could I have an invisible text field?

Comment: @Caroline [textField setHidden:TRUE]; or textfield.hidden = YES;

Comment: Thank you, to everyone who helped I had to set up a text field and become a textfield delegate, I hide the textfield on my screen and the 'done' button resigns first responder. I'll post the code if you would like :), thank you very much :).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)ButtonClicked
{
      [textFld becomeFirstResponder];
      [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

use this method